# How do I determine value of a single attribute from a cluster of attributes?

Tags: differential, clustering, linear-regression

Given price and demand for a cluster of attributes, how can I solve for a single attribute differential?

For example,

Hotel rooms with Standard Layout and King Bed have an average rate of $150 and 600,000 Room Night Stays for the past year.

Hotel rooms with Standard Layout and Queen Bed have an average rate of $130 and 300,000 Room Night Stays for the past year.

Hotel rooms with Suite Layout, King Bed and have an average rate of $160 and 400,000 Room Night Stays for the past year.

An additional layer of View type may be added to the room description. For the purpose of this exercise, how can I determine the driving attribute and its value? Say,

Room rate in USD = Intercept +$a_1*Layout+a_2*BedType+a_3*View+...+a_n*AttributeClass_n$

where,

Intercept = $100

Layout = $   \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      Standard & x \\
      Suite & y \\
\end{array} 
\right. $

BedType = $   \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      King Bed & p \\
      Queen Bed & q \\
\end{array} 
\right. $

View = $   \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      View & c \\
TwoView & d \\
      no View & e \\
\end{array} 
\right. $

It is true that $a_1...a_n$ can be used as weights. It is true that a set of constraints may be used such that,

$Suite + King < y + p$

Please help with this problem by example and/ or references.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I don't see how any of the tags you provided are related to your question... it is also unclear (to me at least) that there would be enough information to determine what you are looking for.

Comment: I have adjusted the tags - differential is related because I am looking for a method to solve for an attribute differential from a cluster of attributes.

Comment: @TravisJ does the additional edit help?

Comment: That helps, but if you are trying to fit a linear model to your data you need at least as many data points (currently 3) as the number of variables (currently 4: intercept, $a_1, a_2, a_3$).  You cannot solve it as is.

Comment: Right. The $a_3$ variable is there if and only if an additional Attribute is included in the cluster.

Comment: I don't think what you are doing is clustering.  I think you are trying to build a linear model to fit the data.  Google: "Linear regression" and look for solving the normal equations.  That will give you the method for computing those coefficients (when it is possible).  My guess is what you are looking for is which coefficient is largest (in absolute value) because that coefficient will have the most impact.

Comment: @TravisJ I think you are right on with linear regression. Yes to which coefficient is largest in absolute value, but also the value of each piece {x,y; p,q; c,d,e}.

Clustering is used because the data elements are currently partitioned into groups. I guess I am looking to $\textbf{decluster}$ to approximate the distance or dissimilarity function.